# Puppeteer: Αccept all cookies in multiple websites with cookie banner

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cookies, puppeteer

I create a script with Node.js and Puppeteer that loads multiple sites like (site A, B, C etc). I want to find all the cookies that site uses.The problem is, that some sites have a Cookie Banner to accept or decline. If you accept the banner the website adds some extra cookies.

So to capture all that cookies is there a general solution to accept all the different banners or to set some initial parameter on header of the initial request to inform the site that I accept all that cookies?

Here is an example of a site with Cookie Bannner initial set 6 cookies and if you accept the banner the total cookies are 48.

https://siteimprove.com/en/gdpr/who-gdpr-affects-and-whose-data-is-protected/

I need a general solution. Because I have a list of websites.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no standard way to do this. Because there is no standard for "cookie banners". If your list of websites isn't terribly large, your best bet is to figure out what the cookie is for each site, store them systematically, and use the appropriate cookies based on the domain being navigated.

UPDATE: see the puppeteer docs here on how to add cookies to your request: https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.4.0&show=api-pagecookiesurls

Comment: How to store the cookies and where? Can you give me an example please?

Comment: okay. So with this way i can get the cookies for an url and after were i can store this cookies? What are you thinking?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the identifiers of cookies banners : https://www.fanboy.co.nz/fanboy-cookiemonster.txt

Comment: Can you provide more informations please? What about this txt?